# About learning semantics

Tags: programming-languages, semantics

I have to do something related with semantics. and I am reading the Semantics Engineering with PLT Redex, I find it a little hard to understand, it is not the way I thought about doing computer science. I remembered how much I am excited about reading CSAPP book. but not ver excited about this one, or the field of semantics! While I think the reason is that I am not yet understanding it, what's the point of it. Maybe. But I think I need some suggestions to lead me out of the way: how to precede the learning of semantics?

Comment: "I have to do something related with semantics."  Does that mean this is homework?  Why not talk to your instructor?

Comment: Yes, I am going to. and at the same time, I would like to see how  other people feel and suggest to work in this area :)

Answer (score 0):

**What is semantics**:  Semantics is usually contrasted with syntax. Syntax describes how pieces of a language may be arranged.  Semantics describes what those arrangements do.  It describes what effects they have.

From the perspective of one who writes a language, syntax is the specification for the lexer, parser and Abstract Syntax Tree.  Semantics is the specification for the Eval / Apply loop.

**Why is semantics interesting**: Syntax is a solved problem. While it is pleasingly complex, once you have written a few good parsers they all start to look the same.  The process of giving a language meaning and having that meaning lead to a useful, concise, and clear tool is a much deeper subject. It is just an opinion, but it common among academics in the Computer Science field to say that semantics make the language.

**Some Semantic Concepts**: Object oriented programing is a semantic notation.  SmallTalk and Java have very different syntax from each other, but share the semantics of "object" as encapsulated data operated on by a defined set of methods.  Functional programing is another semantic idea.

I am not an academic, and I have not kept up with the recent pedagogy of semantics, so I cannot address well what is now being taught, but as a coder and one interested in Computer Science, I find the topic both facinating and highly applicable.